# Enable python support while installing opencv using mac ports

Tags: python, macos, opencv, macports

I installed opencv in my mac using mac ports by the following command

sudo port install opencv

It took around 2 hours and it installed properly. But the problem is that the python bindings are not enabled.

So please let me know how to install opencv in mac using ports and also enable the python bindings. Thanks

PS: I tried to manually compile opencv from source but I am getting lot of errors and I am not able to do it.

Comment: Why not using this : http://code.google.com/p/opencv-cocoa/wiki/Building

Comment: I am not very comfortable with cocoa or Obj C and that's the reason why I am planning to do it using Python itself.

Comment: opencv-cocoa is not an objc binding. it's a fork of opencv with a better cocoa implementation a better quicktime support with 64bits etc etc. it's the same API as opencv ..

Comment: Does this have anything to do with python? (I, too, am having trouble getting Python + opencv to work. I've been trying for several days.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am still not able to compile opencv properly. At last, I found some pre-compiled dmg files from http://vislab.cs.vt.edu/~vislab/wiki/index.php?title=Vision which is working pretty decently.

Answer (score 2):

be sure to have `py26-numpy` installed to have support for basic functions such as `cv.fromarray` :

```
sudo port install py26-numpy
```

`opencv` will compile silently without numpy (it's not *strictly* a dependency).

```
sudo port install -v opencv +python26
```

there you can check that the binding to numpy is effective.

Comment: I just did this. Everything seemed to install OK, but when I fire up Python (and it's the "port" installation, not the Mac default one), I can import numpy, but not opencv.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to compile opencv using cmake on macos (I'm actually doing this) but there is a problem with the videoWriter ...

Have a look there http://www.tsd.net.au/blog/opencv-python-bindings-macports

should be helpful.

Comment: I tried the steps given in the link that you have mentioned. But even then I am not able to get the Python bindings to work properly.